# Calling sizeToFit on a UITextField after changing the font does not work properly on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios7.1

Since iOS 7.1, changing the font size and calling `sizeToFit` does not work as expected. The text will be not be drawn at the correct position and will be cut. The text goes to its correct position when the `UITextField` goes first responder. Calling `resignFirstResponder` will make it fail again though.

[image]

Does anyone have a workaround for that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.text = @"This is a test";
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [textField sizeToFit]; // Calling this will make the second sizeToFit to fail
    textField.font = [textField.font fontWithSize:textField.font.pointSize * 3];
    [textField sizeToFit];
    textField.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    textField.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It's not just the second sizeToFit that has the problem, it's any means of resizing the view after that first sizeToFit call.

Comment: Looks like you've stumbled on a gen-u-wine bug.  Fortunately, as @matt points out, the solution is hopefully pretty easy, just don't do the first sizeToFit.

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug on iOS 8 so I am assuming it has been fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a workaround. Changing the text string before calling sizeToFit will make it work properly:

```
textField.font = [textField.font fontWithSize:textField.font.pointSize * 3];
NSString *oldText = textField.text;
textField.text = @"";
textField.text = oldText;
[textField sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Bravo. I was experimenting along the same lines but you got there first! Very well done. You can also accept your own answer (after a couple of days) to signify that this is the solution. Could you also submit a bug report to Apple?

Comment: Thanks! I submitted a bug report for that case.

Comment: Any word on the bug report? We had the exact same problem and our app's live version was just broken with 7.1 released.

Comment: I don't have any news from them yet. No one seems to have seen my bug report actually.

Comment: Wow you just saved what is left of my sanity! ++++1